# PHP Upload Script corrupting file, Size of file differs from source file

Tags: php

I am running a php script that is executed on a server when someone clicks a button. The script downloads the file from one server stores the file locally then uploads it to another server.

But the file keeps corrupting somewhere in the middle the end file that is uploaded is always a different size and gets corrupted.

Code Below:

```
<?php

//Download CSV Script
// connect and login to FTP and download zip
$ftp_server = "URL REDACTED";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server, 21) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, "USER", "PASS");

// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true);

$local_file = "feed/establishmentexport.zip";
$server_file = "establishmentexport.zip";

// download server file
if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII))
  {
  echo "Successfully downloaded from X.<br />";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error downloading feed. Please reload and retry.<br />";
  }

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);

//End of download.

//FTP UPLOAD SCRIPTS
//Uploading the FTP file EMEA
$ftp_server = "REDACTED";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, "USER", "PASS");
// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true);

$local_file_u = "feed/establishmentexport.zip";

$server_file_u = "custom/establishmentexport.zip";

// upload file
if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $server_file_u, $local_file_u, FTP_ASCII))
  {
  echo "Successfully uploaded to EMEA custom folder.<br />";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error uploading to EMEA custom folder.<br />";
  }

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
//End of Uploading the FTP file

?>
```

Comment: Try using  FTP_BINARY instead of FTP_ASCII

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FTP_ASCII` is intended to be used when handling text files, I believe you should use `FTP_BINARY` in order to properly handle your .zip file.

Replace:

```
ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII)
```

with:

```
ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)
```

And:

```
ftp_put($ftp_conn, $server_file_u, $local_file_u, FTP_ASCII)
```

With:

```
ftp_put($ftp_conn, $server_file_u, $local_file_u, FTP_BINARY)
```

Comment: But if I use FTP binary for a text file like a CSV will that not work or can I use binary for everything?

Comment: You should define the type depending on the file you are getting :)